# AIC-BIC in mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, aic, bic

I was reading about mixed models and I am confused about AIC and BIC criteria. My first question is can I use this types to calculate them?

AIC=2d-2ln(l)

BIC=dln(n)-2ln(l)

where d: is the numbers of parameters.

And my second question, the problem we are facing in mixed model is calculating the number of parameters?